# multiple select and keyboard navigation on md-grid-list, md-grid-tile

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there a way to do multiple selection of md-grid-tile(s) using either ctrl+click or highlight just like in windows explorer?  Also, is it possible to navigate though the grid tiles using keyboard arrow buttons?